# Do achievements work for Netflix?

Tags: achievements, xbox-one, netflix

(I don't know if this is an off topic question since this isn't about a game but 
I don't know where to go to ask this)

So I've done most of the achievements for Netflix on Xbox but I haven't gotten any. I've watched much more than 10 episodes in a row but I haven't gotten that achievement yet. Is there a way to get the achievements or do they just not work?

Comment: _Netflix_ had achievements. _Netflix._ Someday, my grandchildren will ask me what life was like in the late 20-teens and I will not know what to tell them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I can gather from the True Achievements forums, the Netflix achievements may have been discontinued back around August 2017.

https://www.trueachievements.com/forum/viewthread.aspx?tid=823659

Comment: Killing off achievements is clearly a sin in gamer-world.  It isn't clear whether this was caused by MS or Netflix.